# OGNL expression in Core Java - Access a Map with dynamic keys 

Tags: java, ognl

I am new to OGNL. I am trying to write OGNL expressions in core java to retrieve properties/call methods.

Here is my test class.It has a List of keys and a Map which uses these keys to store values.
Please see below

```
package ognl.test;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class OGNLTestProg {

    List<String> keys = null;
    Map<String, Object> data = null;

    public OGNLTestProg(List<String> keys, Map<String, Object> data){
        this.keys = keys;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public List<String> getKeys(){
        return keys;
    }

    public Object getData(String key){
        return data.get(key);
    }
}
```

Here is the test program that instantiates an object of the above class and uses OGNL to call some methods.

```
package ognl.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import ognl.Ognl;

public class Test { 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String str1 = "1";
        String str2 = "2";
        List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();
        keys.add(str1);
        keys.add(str2);

        User u1 = new User();
        u1.setFirstName("x");
        u1.setLastName("y");

        User u2 = new User();
        u2.setFirstName("x1");
        u2.setLastName("y1");

        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        data.put(str1, u1);
        data.put(str2, u2);

        OGNLTestProg o = new OGNLTestProg(keys, data);

        /**
        #{
            #outerObj = #this,
            'users': getKeys().
                {
                    #{  
                    #user = outerObj.getData(#this),
                    #{
                        'firstName': user.getFirstName(),
                        'lastName':user.getLastName()
                    }       
                   }
                }
            }
         */
        Object expression1 = Ognl.parseExpression("#{"+
                  "#outerObj = #this,"+
                  "'users': getKeys()."+
                    "{"+                     
                      "#{"+
                        "#user = outerObj.getData(#this),"+
                        "#{ 'firstName': user.getFirstName(),"+
                            "'lastName':user.getLastName()"+
                        "}"+        
                       "}" +
                       "}"+
                 "}");


        Map<String,Object> map = (Map<String,Object>)Ognl.getValue(expression1, o);

    }

}
```

User is a custom class that has firstName and lastName as properties.

What I am trying to achieve using the OGNL expr is to iterate the list, retrieve each key and then pass that key to the map to retrieve the value (User object) and then call some property on that object.

While I am able to iterate the list using

```
'users': getKeys().{
        //I need to access the getData() method of the root object here passing the current #this object
 }
```

My OGNL expression throws the following error
    Exception in thread "main" ognl.NoSuchPropertyException: java.lang.String.outerObj

Please help. I found tons of stuff on google on using OGNL with struts2 tags, but there's nothing much on its usage to access object properties like above.

Regards,
Suv

Answer (score 0):

If I were going to implement the functionality it looks like you want then I'd probably use a google guava Table object to create the multiple indexed user object which you can then retrieve with a single simple map.get(key) call.

What you have in your example is even matched exactly in the guava Table wiki tutorial on the API.  You're making it more complicated than it has to be otherwise. ;)

Comment: Thanks for your interest and the answer:) I have to implement OGNL for a project that mandates its use as part of its framework. What I posted was a test prototype of a real issue I am facing.

Comment: OGNL is intended to function as an Object Graph Navigation Library, not as general purpose scripting language. I don't think it likes your attempt to assign to a local variable.